# Calculating with decimal

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get the comma number of my int after having calculated it, but i can't seem to get it to work.

My code:

```
int price = 120;
decimal calc = price / 100;
```

But it only returns 1.

Answer (score 4):

```
int price = 120;
decimal calc = price / 100m;
```

your variant:

```
int price = 120;
int temp = price / 100;// temp = 1
decimal calc = (decimal) temp;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int price = 120;
decimal calc = ((decimal)price) / 100;
```

Answer (score 1):

You canculation is being done in integer type as both the operands are integer. It should be:

```
decimal calc = price / 100M; 
                     // ^^^^^
                     //atleast one of the operand should be decimal
```

Or

```
decimal calc = (decimal)price / 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you divide an integer by another integer, result is always an integer. Since you want your answer in more precise way you need to typecast it based on precision that you want. Decimal gives you best possible precision in C#. But even casting to float or double would have also given you answer in the format that you expected. Casting again depends on level of accuracy needed. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b1ff23f%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) is more detailed explanation from MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is declare `price` as decimal also

```
decimal price=120;
decimal calc=price/100;
```

If it is from an argument or another local variable, you can still store it in decimal like:

```
int priceInInt=120;
decimal price=priceInInt;
decimal calc=price/100;
```